# Split a string by ',' but ignore text inside quotes in the string C++ using boost::split

Tags: c++, boost, split

Split a string by `','` but ignore text inside quotes in the string C++ using `boost::split`

Sample string :
`"1,a,2,5,"1,2",5"`

I would like this to be split into different strings as follows,

```
String s1 = "1";
String s2 = "a";
String s3 = "2";
String s4 = "5";
String s5 = "1,2";
String s6 = "5";
```

Can I achieve this using boost::split?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can achieve it. But it will be easier to use an existing csv parsing implementation.

Comment: Also consider if you want your tokens to be able to include escaped quote characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to use `boost::split` in particular, but since you're already using Boost, why not [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/)? Here's a quick implementation using [Spirit X3](http://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/):

```
std::vector<std::string> csvish_split(std::string const& s)
{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    auto const quoted   = '"' >> *~x3::char_('"') >> '"';
    auto const unquoted = *~x3::char_(',');
    auto const segments = (quoted | unquoted) % ',';

    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    if (!x3::parse(cbegin(s), cend(s), segments, ret))
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to parse: " + s);
    return ret;
}
```

**<kbd>[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1710df65732f5d90)</kbd>**

If need be, this can trivially be rewritten using Boost.Spirit.QI.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how to do it with boost tho.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
std::vector<std::string> split_string(const std::string& s)
{
    std::vector<std::string> splitted;
    bool flag = false;
    splitted.push_back("");
    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(s[i]=='\"')
        {
            flag = flag? false : true;
            continue;
        }

        if(s[i]==',' && !flag)
            splitted.push_back("");
        else
            splitted[splitted.size()-1] += s[i];
    }
    return splitted;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::string test = "1,a,2,5,\"1,2\",5";
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    for(auto& x : split_string(test))
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1,a,2,5,"1,2",5 
1 
a 
2 
5 
1,2 
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, that was helpful. I finally solved this using Boost::tokenize. That did what I wanted.